# tcsh alias with complex cmds, quotes and cmd arguments

Tags: command-line, alias, tcsh

I'm tying to alias a set of pipe commands, went thru some of the threads here and found that cmd line should be used differently.
instead of $1 use !:1  but it doesn't seem to work for me in the below context

This is my set of cmds that I'm wanting to alias (its calculating median)

```
shell>  cat file_with_numbers| awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'
shell> 1.15
```

I want to alias the below part as "median"

```
sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'
```

so I can just use

`shell> cat file_with_numbers| awk '{print $1}' | median`

```
alias median 'sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }''
```

Badly placed ()'s.
//single quotes errored out

```
alias median "sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=$1; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'"

cat file| awk '{print $5}'|  median
awk:  { a[i++]=; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }
awk:           ^ syntax error
```

so I switched to `\!:1` &  tried the following and it still didn't work.
how can I have this aliased properly?

1> trial 1

```
alias median "sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=\!:1; } END { x=int ( ( i+1 ) /2 ) ; if ( x < ( i+1 ) /2 ) print ( a[x-1]+a[x] ) /2 ; else print a[x-1] ; }' "


cat file|  awk '{print $5}' | median
Bad ! arg selector.
```

2> trial 2

```
alias median "sort -n | awk ' { a[i++]=\\!:1; } END { x=int ( ( i+1 ) /2 ) ; if ( x < ( i+1 ) /2 ) print ( a[x-1]+a[x] ) /2 ; else print a[x-1] ; }' "

cat file| awk '{print $5}' | median
awk:  { a[i++]=!:1; } END { x=int ( ( i+1 ) /2 ) ; if ( x < ( i+1 ) /2 ) print ( a[x-1]+a[x] ) /2 ; else print a[x-1] ; }
awk:            ^ syntax error
```

trial 3>

Comment: If the `alias` is just going to be in a `.bashrc` or `.profile` file, you could also build a complex function in that file, and then call the function from the command line, or build an alias to the function.

Comment: @Tim, the `alias mediam "..."` syntax and the `shell> ` prompt suggest the OP is using csh or tcsh. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a single-line command sequence in an alias, but you may need to add backslashes and single or double quotes here and there. But unless you need to invoke the alias with parameters or elements from the shell's history, or need to maximize speed, sometimes it's easier to just put the command sequence as-is into a file, mark it as executable, and place it somewhere in your search path (`$PATH` or `$path`).

But to make the following into an alias:

```
sort -n | awk '{ a[i++]=$1; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'
```

You need to make sure that

- the pipeline operator is within a string that is enclosed by quotes; otherwise it will terminate the alias command
- the `$` is either within a string that is enclosed by single quotes, or is outside of any quoted string and is preceded by a `\` (thanks, Stéphane, for the alternative)
- there are no nested single quotes

Don't use `\!:1` to try to produce `$1`. `\!:1` would be used if you passed a parameter to your alias. You just want the literal `$1` to be seen by awk.

The safest thing to do in this case is to enclose as much of the alias as possible with single quotes, and use `"` only to surround a literal single quote. You'll see two occurrences of `"'"` below.

```
ubuntu% alias median 'sort -n | awk '"'"'{ a[i++]=$1 ; } END { x=int ( ( i+1 ) /2 ) ; if ( x < ( i+1 ) /2 ) print ( a[x-1]+a[x] ) /2 ; else print a[x-1] ; }'"'"

ubuntu% seq 1 9 | median
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you care about reinventing the wheel, you could also use GNU `datamash`:

```
alias median 'datamash median 1'
```

`datamash` expects tab delimited columns, though you can change the delimiter with `-t`.

For your particular problem, note that `$parameter` expansion in (t)csh is done inside double quotes, but contrary to Bourne-like shells, it can't be disabled with backslashes, so you'd need something like:

```
alias median "sort -n | awk '{a[NR]="\$"1}; END {x = int(NR/2); print NR % 2 ? a[x+1] : (a[x]+a[x+1])/2}'"
```

That is get out of the double quotes to enter the `$` as `\$`, or go with Mark's approach and use single quotes but get out of them to enter literal single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ alias median="sort -n|awk ' { a[i++]="\$1"; } END { x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1]; }'"

$ cat file_with_numbers| awk '{print $1}'|median
```

Comment: To fully qualify as a useful answer, please _explain_ your solution.

Comment: Note that the OP seems to be using `csh` or `tcsh`. `alias a=cmd` is ksh/POSIX syntax.